# Stolen Server Memory and Database Cache Memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, memory

I have the same behavior in 2 SQL Servers where Stolen Server Memory and Database Cache Memory counters are decreasing (Db Cache) and increasing (Stolen Memory) in a linear way. The amount of memory decreased from Db Cache Memory is almost the same amount of memory increased in Stolen Memory.
Has anyone seeing this behavior before? Is it an expected behavior?

Both server's configuration:

- SQL Server 2012 ENTERPRISE with SP3
- 32GB memory

Thanks for the attention

Comment: I have wrestled with this problem on an instance of SQL Server used to run a SharePoint environment for some time, and never really solved it. Stolen memory creeps up and up until users performance dips because PLE is at rock bottom. Rebooting the server during weekly maintenance windows keeps things running smoothly for me.